# Is parallel asynchronous execution where a thread sleeps using multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

This is the code that I wrote to better understand asynchronous methods. I knew that an asynchronous method is not the same as multithreading, but it does not seem so in this particular scenario:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        //the line above just makes sure that the console output uses . to represent doubles instead of ,
        ExecuteAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task ParallelAsyncMethod() //this is the method where async parallel execution is taking place
    {
        List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DownloadWebsite()));
        }

        var strings = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (var str in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

    private static string DownloadWebsite() //Imitating a website download
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500); //making the thread sleep for 1500 miliseconds before returning
        return "Download finished";
    }

    private static async void ExecuteAsync()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await ParallelAsyncMethod();
        watch.Stop();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"It took the machine {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds" +
            $" or {Convert.ToDouble(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds) / 1000} seconds to complete this task");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

//OUTPUT:
    /*
    Download finished
    Download finished
    Download finished
    Download finished
    Download finished
    It took the machine 1537 milliseconds or 1.537 seconds to complete this task
    */
```

As you can see, the `DownloadWebsite` method waits for 1.5 seconds and then returns "a". The method called `ParallelAsyncMethod` adds five of these methods into the "tasks" list and then starts the parallel asynchronous execution. As you can see, I also tracked the amount of time that it takes for the `ExecuteAsync` method to be executed. The result is always somewhere around 1540 milliseconds. Here is my question: if the `DownloadWebsite` method required a thread to sleep 5 times for 1500 milliseconds, does it mean that the parallel execution of these methods required 5 different threads? If not, then how come it only took the program 1540 milliseconds to be executed and not ~7500 ms?

Comment: Mandatory: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @John Wu I read it. It’s a great article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I knew that an asynchronous method is not the same as multi-threading

That is correct, an asynchronous method releases the current thread whilst I/O occurs, and schedules a continuation after it's completion.

Async and threads are completely unrelated concepts.

> but it does not seem so in this particular scenario

That is because you explicitly run `DownloadWebsite` on the ThreadPool using `Task.Run`, which imitates asynchronous code by returning a `Task` after instructing the provided delegate to run.

Because you are not waiting for each `Task` to complete before starting the next, multiple threads can be used simultaneously.

Currently each thread is being blocked, as you have used `Thread.Sleep` in the implementation of `DownloadWebsite`, meaning you are actually running 5 synchronous methods on the ThreadPool.

---

In production code your `DownloadWebsite` method should be written asynchronously, maybe using `HttpClient.GetAsync`:

```
private static async Task<string> DownloadWebsiteAsync()
{
    //...
    await httpClinet.GetAsync(//...
    //...
}
```

In that case, `GetAsync` returns a `Task`, and *releases the current thread* whilst waiting for the HTTP response.

You can still run multiple async methods concurrently, but as the thread is released each time, this may well use less than 5 separate threads and may even use a single thread.

Ensure that you dont use `Task.Run` with an asynchronous method; this simply adds unnecessary overhead:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(DownloadWebsiteAsync()); // No need for Task.Run
}

var strings = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

---

As an aside, if you want to imitate an async operation, use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` as the former is non-blocking:

```
private static async Task<string> DownloadWebsite() //Imitating a website download
{
    await Task.Delay(1500); // Release the thread for ~1500ms before continuing
    return "Download finished";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I’d like to clarify one thing, though. What do you mean by “releasing a thread”?

Comment: @Itsme1 Rather than blocking a thread whilst waiting for the I/O response, release it to the ThreadPool to serve other requests. This could also be the UI-thread if your targeting a desktop app, and releasing the thread keeps the UI responsive.